# Stacking of Elements in HTML having CSS positions

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the HTML elements.
I have made a parent HTML div with position relative and it has 2 child, one with position absolute (1st child) and other with default position (2nd child).

```
    <body>
      <div id="parent">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

The CSS of the elements is

```
#parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

#child1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#child2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

Now, I have added an event listener on child2. But the event is fired
on element with "child2" class only on the portion outside of "child1".
But when I changes the position of element "child2" to relative, I get 
the event fired on the entire "child2" element.

What is the reason for this behavior ?

```
var el = document.getElementById("child2");  
el.addEventListener("click", 
      function () {   
          alert("Hello"); 
      });
```

The link to JSFiddle is :

> http://jsfiddle.net/GS2306/peby5Lgk/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not define any position property on `#child2` then it is static. Static divs are overlapped by absolute and relative positioned divs because they don't have [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Therefore, you get click event only on `#child2` where it is not overlapped by `#child1`.

But when you set the `#child2` position to relative then it overlaps `#child1`( as `#child2` is inserted after `#child1` and both have same z-index). Hence you are able to get click event on whole `#child2` as it is not overlapped by `#child1` now

Answer (score 0):

Adding background colors to your elements makes it clear why the observed behaviour is happening. Your absolutely positioned element - `#child1` - is "on top" of your statically positioned element- `#child2`

```js
var el = document.getElementById("child2");
el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

```css
#parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
#child1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    opacity:0.8;
    background: #f0f;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#child2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: #f00;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When you change the above snippet to set `position: relative` on `#child2` you'll see that `#child2` now appears "on top" of `#child1`.

The CSS spec states that positioned elements always appear higher in the stacking order than non-positioned (`position: static`) elements. If two elements are both positioned and have no `z-index` specified on them, their stacking order defined as their paint order (elements that occur later in the markup will appear on top of elements that occur earlier in the markup).

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply. The concept is clear to me now.